# Trying to set a recursive function inside a promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
let cancelDownload = true
const delay = () => {
    return new Promise(() => {
            if (cancelDownload === true){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('Delaying...');
                    delay();
                }, 1000);
            }
            else return null;
            });
};
const cancelJob = async() => {
    for(let i = 6; i>0; i--){
        console.log('inside for ',i);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            cancelDownload = false
        },4000)
        await delay()
        console.log('aaaaaaaa');
        console.log(`the number is ${i}`);
    }
}

cancelJob()
```

I am trying to write a delay function whereby once the condition is met delay is removed and all code is resumed but it seems that once the delay is done the code exits without executing the last two console logs

[image: Console log message below]

Comment: The closure you passed to the `Promise` constructor doesn’t invoke the accept callback. See <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises>.

Comment: 1. Why use recursion here at all? 2. Your promise is never resolved as pointed out by user3840170. You need to resolve it. 3. But with a recursion, you must make sure to resolve the top-most promise, not just the last inner one or similar. 4. The last point doesn't mean recursion is *hard* or bad but it is more complex than it probably needs to be.

Comment: @VLAZ How can I resolve it without recursion? I am really confused, maybe I am looking at the whole problem wrong. appreciate your answer

Comment: @anoopfrancis [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) - start an interval, check your condition periodically, when it's finished `resolve()` or `reject()` the promise as appropriate and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Comment: @VLAZ okay I will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No recursion needed. Instead, you can:

1. Use [`setInteval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to check your condition every second.
2. When the condition is correct, you need to resolve the promise.
3. Use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

```js
let cancelDownload = true
const delay = () => {
    let intervalId;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const check = () => {
        if (cancelDownload === true){
            console.log('Delaying...');
        } else  {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          resolve();
        }
      }
      //check immediately
      check();
      //then check every second afterwards
      intervalId = setInterval(check, 1000);
    });
};
const cancelJob = async() => {
    for(let i = 6; i>0; i--){
        console.log('inside for ',i);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            cancelDownload = false
        },4000)
        await delay()
        console.log('aaaaaaaa');
        console.log(`the number is ${i}`);
    }
}

cancelJob()
```

This can be generalised a bit in the following fashion - instead of hard-coding the condition, supply it as a callback. Then you can have a `delay` function without using global variables and it can wait for different things, not just one single variable.

```js
const delayWhile = shouldWait => () => {
    let intervalId;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const check = () => {
        if (shouldWait()){
            console.log('Delaying...');
        } else  {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          resolve();
        }
      }
      //check immediately
      check();
      //then check every second afterwards
      intervalId = setInterval(check, 1000);
    });
};

const cancelJob = async() => {
    let cancelDownload = true;
    const delay = delayWhile(() => cancelDownload);
    
    for(let i = 6; i>0; i--){
        console.log('inside for ',i);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            cancelDownload = false
        },4000)
        await delay()
        console.log('aaaaaaaa');
        console.log(`the number is ${i}`);
    }
}

cancelJob()
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you pass to the promise constructor (the *promise executor* function) is called with two arguments: a function to use to resolve the promise and a function to reject it (conventionally called `resolve` and `reject`). Your code should call one of those functions when your asynchronous work is done.

Yours isn't, so the promise never settles, and your code waits forever at the `await`.

But there are other issues:

1. If you call `delay` again, it creates a **new** promise. Your code using `await` only has access to the first promise, not the ones created by those recursive calls. There isn't really any reason to use recursion here at all.

2. All calls to the function share the **same** flag. So if we fix the issue with not fulfilling the promise, the loop does wait, but only once:

```js
let cancelDownload = false;
const delay = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        tick();
        function tick() {
            // Cancelled?
            if (cancelDownload) {
                // Yes, fulfill the promise
                console.log("Flag is set, fulfilling");
                resolve(null);
            } else {
                // No, wait another second
                console.log("waiting 1000 and checking again");
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
};
const cancelJob = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Setting cancelDownload to true");
        cancelDownload = true;
    }, 4000);
    for (let i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
        console.log("inside for ", i);
        await delay();
        console.log("aaaaaaaa");
        console.log(`the number is ${i}`);
    }
};

cancelJob();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I may be mistaken that that second one is a problem for your use case, though, since in a comment on a now-deleted answer you said you wanted the loop only to wait once (the "whole loop" rather than just one iteration).

If you want a function that polls a flag (I don't recommend it, polling is generally not best practice, though sometimes you can't avoid it) and fulfills a promise when it's set, you could use `AbortController`:

```js
const delay = (signal) => {
    let done = false;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        tick();
        function tick() {
            // Cancelled?
            if (signal.aborted) {
                // Yes, fulfill the promise with null
                console.log("Fulfilling with null");
                resolve(null);
            } else {
                // No, wait another second
                console.log("Waiting 1000 and checking again");
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
};
const cancelJob = async () => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Cancelling");
        controller.abort();
    }, 4000);
    for (let i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
        console.log("inside for ", i);
        await delay(controller.signal);
        console.log("aaaaaaaa");
        console.log(`the number is ${i}`);
    }
};

cancelJob();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That also only delays the loop once, because we're passing the same signal to all of the `delay` functions. Originally I was creating that inside the loop, like this:

```js
const delay = (signal) => {
    let done = false;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        tick();
        function tick() {
            // Cancelled?
            if (signal.aborted) {
                // Yes, fulfill the promise with null
                console.log("Fulfilling with null");
                resolve(null);
            } else {
                // No, wait another second
                console.log("Waiting 1000 and checking again");
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
};
const cancelJob = async () => {
    for (let i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Cancelling");
            controller.abort();
        }, 4000);
        console.log("inside for ", i);
        await delay(controller.signal);
        console.log("aaaaaaaa");
        console.log(`the number is ${i}`);
    }
};

cancelJob();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...but then I saw the "whole loop" comment on the other answer.

Note: Normally when you have an asynchronous process with a cancel feature like that, it rejects on cancel with a cancel-specific rejection reason rather than fulfilling, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to cancellable promises is to supply the promise creator function with a writable parameter like `cancelToken`. The promise creator populates this parameter with a callback, which, when invoked, cancels this particular promise. This usually leads to simpler and more linear code.

```js
let pause = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));

async function job(name, steps, cancelToken) {
    let cancelled = false;

    cancelToken.callback = () => cancelled = true;

    for (let step = 1; step <= steps; step++) {
        console.log(name, step);

        await pause();

        if (cancelled) {
            console.log('CANCELLED');
            break;
        }
    }
}


async function main() {
    let cancelToken = {};

    let job1 = job('ok', 5, cancelToken);
    await job1;

    let job2 = job('bad', 5, cancelToken);
    setTimeout(cancelToken.callback, 100);
    await job2;
}

main()
```

As a general hint, it's better to avoid `new Promise` and callbacks whether possible. Note how in this example `Promise` and `setTimeout` are only used for testing purposes (simulate real work) and the rest of the code won't change once we replace `pause` with something more useful like `fetch`.